# CSS no text wrap

Tags: html, css, text

Please see see code http://jsbin.com/eveqe3/edit, also quoted below.

I need to show text inside the item divs in such a way the text appear only in the green box with specified width rest of the line need to be hidden. Any suggestions please...

```
<style>
  #container{
    width : 220px;
  }
  .item{
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #0a0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 12px;
    padding 2px;
    margin: 0px 2px;
  }
  .clearfix{
    clear: both;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item"> A very loooooooooooooooooooooong text </div>
    <div class="item"> Another looooooooooooooooooooong text </div>
    <div class="clearfix">  </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Just an FYI, if you set your height to 12px, with 2px padding you should use font-size:10px so the border does not cover the bottom of the characters.  I prefer to use EM as a measure instead though so that it scales better on user changes.

Comment: Be sure to view your result in all your target browsers as the font/size differs by default.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Additionally to overflow:hidden, use

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Comment: yeah!, this one is what I want!

Comment: Just thought I might add something here as I could not get my block of <pre> to stop wrapping, a preceding pre {} css element was of course over-riding anything else I was trying to do with .pre {} class. This might be the cause of some people's grief with wrapping.

Answer (score 42):

Just use:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

In your item's divs

Answer (score 4):

Use the css property overflow . For example:

```
  .item{
    width : 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
```

The overflow property can have one of many values like ( **hidden** , **scroll** , **visible** ) .. you can als control the overflow in one direction only using **overflow-x** or **overflow-y**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please see `overflow:hidden` applied here jsbin.com/eveqe3/2/edit , the a portion of the second line is visible in the box. Is it possible to avoid text coming into next line?