# How do you make sure a multi-word term wraps together and does not break?

Tags: php, html, css

On the page http://www.canadianwhoswho.ca/about-cww.php the heading:

## Letter from the former Governor General, 100th anniversary edition of *Canadian Who’s Who*

looks good on some screen sizes, but on smaller screens sometimes the second Who is on the next line.  My client would like the term "Canadian Who's Who" to always be on the same line.  How would one achieve this?

Comment: One way would be to use "&nbsp;" instead of normal spaces between the words. CSS would use the white-space nowrap approach i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308365/css-no-text-wrap"

Comment: Thank you Marvin. It all seems so simple now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is the easiest way to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you Jason; seems I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  After Marvin made that suggestion I added the non-breaking spaces and they worked like a charm.