# overflow-x: scroll is not taken into account

Tags: html, css

Please see this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n8rk814p/1/

The text on the `ed` div is wrapped. I would like it to scroll horizontally if the content is too big. It seems like my `overflow-x:scroll` is not taken into account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS no text wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308365/css-no-text-wrap)

Comment: The answer is the same, though I don't think the questions are duplicate. I thought I didn't need to set `white-space` to `nowrap` in the case of `overflow-x:scroll`.

Comment: It's my guess, but I think if you do not set it, whitespace gets wrapped by default, preventing overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/n8rk814p/2/

Just add

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to the styles