# CSS Problem: Can't get UL element to not wrap text

Tags: html, css

I have looked at a few similar posts but I can't seem to get this to work. I am writing a menu for a webpage and am having problems with items in a UL wrapping around.

What I want to see is the UL contents (all 8 menu items) on a single line and not wraparound (displays 6 menu items on top row, and wraps other two on to a new line). Also the line that appears under the text when highlighted to appear in the middle of the centered text. See the following for what I mean about the alignment.

```
What I expect: 
  WhoWeAre    Our Team   Farming   Products   Customers   Recruitment   Latest News  Contact Us
             ----------

What I get: (note miss aligned line) 
  WhoWeAre    Our Team   Farming   Products   Customers   Recruitment   Latest News  Contact Us
                                -----------
```

HTML

```
<div class="sitemenu2">
  <table style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #79288C;text-decoration: none;">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="./images/smallLogo.png" style="padding-right:20px"></td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li class="menuOption1" href="./whoweare.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Who We Are</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption2" href="./ourteam.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Our Team</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption3" href="./farming.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Farming</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption4" href="./products.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Products</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption5" href="./customers.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Customers</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption6" href="./recruitment.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Recruitment</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption7" href="./news.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Latest News</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption8" href="./contactus.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Contact Us</a></li>
          <hr />
        </ul>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sitemenu2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

.menulink {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.5%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.menuOption2:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 12.5%;
}

.menuOption3:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.menuOption4:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 37.5%;
}

.menuOption5:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.menuOption6:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 62.5%;
}

.menuOption7:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

.menuOption8:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 87.5%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 12.5%;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #79288C;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

JSFiddle with all the code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/idrinktea/m0jd6r42/6/

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets, not external code sites.

Comment: `I have looked at a few similar posts but I can't seem to get this to work` . Did you try to search on google for eg ' css not wrap text ' ( that is your question title ) ? If you would've the first result is -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308365/css-no-text-wrap second is ->  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp . How can you say you looked everywhere but didn't find a solution ?

Comment: I have seen similar posts and tried applying some of the CSS but I couldn't get it to work for me. Hence why I am wondering if there is somethign spefici in my CSS that is at fault here or if it's because I've got it housed with a table that it's behaving oddly.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: in both of the above links, the solution is `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent element. so in your case,, the `ul` . DOes that not work ? ( for the wrap problem )

Comment: HI Mihai, I never said I looked everywhere, I searched similar questions (here on Stack Overflow). Please don't misquote me. I did google it but used more specific search terms, which I now realise caused the answer to be excluded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `<ul>` tag:

```css
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sitemenu2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

.menulink {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.5%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.menuOption2:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 12.5%;
}

.menuOption3:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.menuOption4:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 37.5%;
}

.menuOption5:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.menuOption6:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 62.5%;
}

.menuOption7:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

.menuOption8:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 87.5%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 12.5%;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #79288C;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<-->
  What I want to see is the UL contents (all 8 menu items) on a single line and not wraparound and for the line that appears under the text when highlighted to appear in the middle of the centered text. See the following for what I mean about the alignment.
  Good: WhoWeAre Our Team Farming Products Customers Recruitment Latest News Contact Us ---------- Bad: WhoWeAre Our Team Farming Products Customers Recruitment Latest News Contact Us -----------
</-->
<div class="sitemenu2">
  <table style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #79288C;text-decoration: none;">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="./images/smallLogo.png" style="padding-right:20px"></td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li class="menuOption1" href="./whoweare.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Who We Are</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption2" href="./ourteam.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Our Team</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption3" href="./farming.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Farming</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption4" href="./products.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Products</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption5" href="./customers.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Customers</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption6" href="./recruitment.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Recruitment</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption7" href="./news.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Latest News</a></li>
          <li class="menuOption8" href="./contactus.html"><a class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none; color:#79288C">Contact Us</a></li>
          <hr />
        </ul>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```